# How to optimize numpy operation, applying 2D condition on 3 channel RGB image?

Tags: python, numpy, slice, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to apply a computation from 2D alpha image to 3 channeled RGB image. I need to update pixel intensity in each channel, based on respective pixel value in 2D alpha image. Below is one MWE I created to illustrate the concept.

**MWE:**

```
# test alpha 2D image
test_a1 = np.array([
    [0, 0, 50], 
    [0, 0, 150],
    [0, 0, 225]
    ])

# test 3 channel RGB image
test_ir1 = np.ones((3,3,3))

# getting indices of alpha where cond is satisfied
idx = np.unravel_index(np.where(test_a1.ravel()>0),test_a1.shape)
test_output = np.zeros_like(test_ir1)
n_idx = len(idx[0][0])

# applying computation on 3 channel RGB image only where cond is satisfied.
for i in range(n_idx):

    # multiply only where test_a1 > 0
    r_idx, c_idx = idx[0][0][i], idx[1][0][i]
    test_output[r_idx,c_idx,0] = test_a1[r_idx, c_idx] * test_ir1[r_idx, c_idx, 0]
    test_output[r_idx,c_idx,1] = test_a1[r_idx, c_idx] * test_ir1[r_idx, c_idx, 1]
    test_output[r_idx,c_idx,2] = test_a1[r_idx, c_idx] * test_ir1[r_idx, c_idx, 2]

test_output = test_output.astype('uint8')
plt.imshow(test_output, vmin=0, vmax=3)
```

**output:**
[image]

I basically tried to find the indices in 2D alpha image, where condition is met, and tried to apply those indices to all channels of the image.

Is there a way to optimize above operation (not for channel looping)?  I am specifically looking to avoid the for loop in the code, doing numpy for each index. It is ver slow for regular images.

Answer (score 0):

You might observe that:
`test_output = np.einsum('ij,ijk->ijk', test_a1, test_ir1)`
 
Not sure if this helps reformulate a slightly different MWE if this isnt precisely what you intend

=== edited ===

I would still make use of `einsum` since it allows you a lot of control of vectorised multidimensional linear algebra.

Provided you can reduce your operations to some mathematical description, for example:

> Where `test_a1` is greater than zero, double the intensity of the pixels measured over each channel.

Then you do that in the following way:

```
mask = test_a1 > 0
output = np.einsum('ij,ijk->ijk', mask, test_ir1) + test_ir1
```

Comment: thank you I am looking for a way to avoid for loop to do operation for each (r,c) indices. That is ill way of using numpy usually.